# Hide arrow and highlighting when press on NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have NavigationLink in List, and when I click to it, it highlights item. And also arrow shows at the right corner

```
NavigationLink(destination: ItemsListView()) {                    
                Text("Show all (\(body.count))")
                                 .font(.body)
                                 .foregroundColor(Color.red)
}
```

How can hide the arrow in the right corner, and also disable highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the selection style of the cell by doing the following.

- Create an init function for the struct that contains your `List`
- Get the appearance for `UITableViewCell`
- Set the `selectionStyle` to be `.none`

Here is some example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        let appearance = UITableViewCell.appearance()
        appearance.selectionStyle = .none
        // appearance.accessoryType = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List(0..<5, id: \.self) { element in

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(element)")) {

                    Text("\(element)")

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be possible to hide the `accessoryType` of the cell by setting it to `.none` as well (see the commented out code above) but it doesn't seem possible at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the `selectionStyle = .none`, made my day!

Comment: @emreoktem can you find any solution for iOS 14?

Answer (score -1):

```
 .opacity(0.0) // just add this to the navigationLink

 NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(element)")) {Text("\(element)")} .opacity(0.0)
```